# while printing a pdf table breaking and calculations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table where while printing table is getting split in multiple pages , but i have few calculations when moving to next page

so while printing here the table row is getting split into two pages , and i want to add the remaining data to calculate what is the total in this page and carry forward that sum to next page , is there any way to identify this table brake ?

[image]

Sharing the html table structure :

```
    <table
            id="details_report"
            style={{
              fontSize:12,
              borderCollapse: 'collapse',
              border: '1px solid black',
              width: '100%',
              margin: '0px',
            }}
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td
                  colspan="3"
                >
                 Name of table
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style={{ borderTop: '1px solid black' }}>
                <td
                  style={{ paddingLeft: 15, fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                >
                  Note
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    paddingLeft: 12,
                  }}
                >
                  PARTICULARS
                </td>
                  <td
                    data-a-h="end"
                    style={{
                      textAlign: 'center',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      paddingRight: 20,
                    }}
                  >
                    As at 31/03/2020
                 </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Data &&
                Data.map((el, i) => (
                  <>
                    <tr>
                      <td
                      >
                        {el.note_number}{G_Children[el.detail_number - 1]})
                      </td>
                      <td
                      >
                        <strong>{el.account}</strong>
                      </td>
                      <td/>
                    </tr>

                    {el.children.map((el2, j) => (
                      <>
                        <tr>
                          <td />
                          <td>{el2.account}</td>
                          <td >{el2.total}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {/* after every 5 entry need space */}
                        {el.children.length !== j + 1 &&
                          (j + 1) % 5 === 0 && (
                            <tr style={{ height: 15 }}>
                              <td className="emptytd" colspan="3" />
                            </tr>
                          )}
                      </>
                    ))}

                    <tr>
                      <td colSpan="2"/>
                      <td>{el.total}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </>
                ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

For Json Data i have attached a file

Comment: Hi, the PDF  file provided from the backend?

Comment: Hi Nevr , no pdf is getting constructed in the front end itself i am getting an array of  objects and i am constructing this pdf .

Comment: as far as I know there is no way to detect page break while generating the PDF file, 
just you can count the items or rows, something like how many rows you can put inside a one PDF page. So that will allow you to make calculations before generating the PDF page.
I can go into the details in case you will need it.

Comment: That will be very helpful I am stuck in here since 15 days let me share all the details , if time permits please look into it.

Comment: No Problem will try to help you till the end of the day

Comment: sharing more details in the question itself @NverAbgaryan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231353/discussion-between-bhart-supriya-and-nver-abgaryan).